# Additional gap after addition of another image

Tags: html, css

[image: Before-image]

This is before I added the text for the footer. The footer image rested nicely against the bottom of the page.

[image: After-image]

This is after I added the text for the footer.

I can't find the issue that causes the mysterious additional gap at the bottom of the page. Ignore the black border- I used it to check the margins of the footer text image.

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}



body {
    background-image: url('images/BG-W1.png');
}
#container{
    max-width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    position: relative; 
    padding: 0 auto;
    height: 790px;
    border: 2px solid blue;

}

#footerBg {
    position: relative;
    bottom:-63px;
    left:-50px;
}

#footerBg img {
    display: block;
}

#footertex {
    position: relative;
    top:-110px;

    border:2px solid black;

}
footer {
    height: 50px;
} 

#footertex img {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer>
            <figure id="footerBg">
                <img src="images/BG_F_S3.png" alt="Footer Background" width="" height="" />

            </figure>   

        <<figure id="footertex">    
                    <img src="images/ft1.png" usemap="#green" border="0" />

                    <map name="green">

                    <area shape="rect" coords="513,56,625,106" href="http://www.google.com" />
                    <area shape="rect" coords="725,58,874,108" href="http://www.google.com" />

                    </map>
        </figure>   

        </footer>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your CSS and HTML?

Comment: I'm a little confused, can you show us your html?

Comment: Posted. Oh gosh, totally forgotten about posting the code at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your HTML & CSS code? A quick fix that comes to mind would be `div#footer { box-sizing: border-box; }` but showing what you already have will hopefully get you a better answer.

Comment: You have an extra open tag before `<figure id="footertex">`. Also, I don't see why you have so much negative positioning on your footer elements. Essentially, your `<figure id="footerBg">` would sit outside of its parent element `<footer>`. Is this intentional?